# What's the right method to set a new prerender or prefetch in HTML?

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, prefetch, prerender

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>An HTML Document</title>
<link rel="prefetch" href="https://www.apple.com/">
<link rel="prerender" href="https://www.apple.com/">
<script>
    document.addEventListener('click', function () {
        // Prerendering https://www.apple.com/ipad on Chrome.
        // ...

        // Prefetching https://www.apple.com/ipad on Firefox.
        // ...
    }, false);
</script>
```

When the page is opened, https://www.apple.com/ is prerendered and prefetched on different browsers. When the document is clicked, I hope to prerender and prefetch another page, https://www.apple.com/ipad.

It appears we have 2 methods to choose. We can either replace the URLs in current 2 `link` elements. Or we can insert 2 new `link` elements into `head` element.

What's the right method to set a new prerender in HTML?

What's the right method to set a new prefetch in HTML?

I tried to replace prerender `link` element's URL from https://www.apple.com/ to https://www.apple.com/ipad on Chrome. I turned Chrome's Task manager on and found that https://www.apple.com/ipad wasn't prerednered. The only prerendered page is still https://www.apple.com/. So it appears this method doesn't work?

Answer (score 17):

`<link rel="prefetch">` is actually part of the [HTML 5 spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#link-type-prefetch).

`<link rel="prerender">` appears to be [Google doing their own thing](https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/prerender).

[Justin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/201853/justin) is incorrect. You do need both prefetch and prerender (or at least a polyfill that will output both) as [FF supports prefetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Link_prefetching_FAQ) and [Chrome supports prerender](https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/prerender).

Comment: IE11 now supports both.

Comment: Best approach would be to combine both, eg, `<link rel="prefetch prerender" href="http://example.com/">`?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you confused me a little with the mixing between `prefetch` & `prerender` usages. Their usages should be like this:

**`prefetch` usage:**

It should be used for fetching and caching resources for later user navigation as per the [official HTML5 spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#link-type-prefetch) (i.e. prefetching a css file to be used in a page which highly likely to be used by the user in his upcoming navigation). *Supported in Chrome, Firefox & IE*.

**`prerender` usage:**

It should be used for prerendering a complete page that the user will highly likely navigate to it in his upcoming navigation (i.e. like prerendering the next article where it is highly likely that the user will click on "next article" button). *Supported only in Chrome & IE*.

---

**Back to your question**, you can add browser hints (i.e. like the two `link` you used) as many as you really need, just don't misuse them because they are resource-heavy.

So, you can inject your hints when the page is generated (like what you did), or you can inject them at *runtime* using javascript like this:

```
var hint = document.createElement("link");
hint.setAttribute("rel", "prerender");
hint.setAttribute("href", "https://www.apple.com/ipad");

document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(hint);
```

For a better understanding for what you can do with all `"pre-"` goodies, see this brilliant [presentation by google](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/18zlAdKAxnc51y_kj-6sWLmnjl6TLnaru_WH0LJTjP-o/present?slide=id.p19).