# Javascript Timer for pre-render/prefetch blanks page

Tags: javascript, html, timer, prerender

The JS timer blanks all content on the page when it runs out.

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
document.write("<link rel='prerender' href='http://google.com' />")


}
,10000
);
```

The effect happens both when the JS is placed within the head and in the body.

How do I do a prefetch/prerender based on a timer without having my page turned blank? (all content vanishes. there is no url redirection. i'm left with a blank page)

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099915/whats-the-right-method-to-set-a-new-prerender-or-prefetch-in-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.write can only be used before the document is ready for display. It should be used inline while it is building. If used after document is ready it will cause issues like your facing.

If you are using jQuery you can use their [getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) function:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {

    $.getScript('script.js',function(){
       //this is your callback function to execute after the script loads
    });
}
,10000
);
```

Or if using only javascript [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839698/jquery-getscript-alternative-in-native-javascript) question may be useful to you. They use:

```
(function(d, t) {
var g = d.createElement(t), // create a script tag
    s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0]; // find the first script tag in the document
g.src = 'your-script.js'; // set the source of the script to your script
s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s); // append the script to the DOM
}(document, 'script'));
```

Comment: As per your answer, I used jQuery and then used $("head").append('<link rel="prerender" href="http://google.com">'); and that worked without blanking the page.

I couldn't get it work with the external script (with and without jquery).